# How to add a directory to the system path environment variable using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, exe, cx-freeze

I have developed an application in Python and I am distributing the *.exe* of the app by freezing the code with `cx_Freeze`.

A [package](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#id3) in my application (`cx_Oracle`) requires the user to add a directory to the **PATH** environment variable.

Is there a way to do so making use of `bdist_msi` command in `cx_Freeze` setup script without having the user to do it manually?

For example, if I wanted to add `C:\folder1` to the **PATH**, how should I modify the following code?

```
'bdist_msi': {
    'upgrade_code': upgrade_code,
    'add_to_path': True,
    'environment_variables': [
        ("E_MYAPP_VAR", "=-*MYAPP_VAR", "1", "TARGETDIR")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
'bdist_msi': {
    'upgrade_code': upgrade_code,
    'add_to_path': True,
    'environment_variables': [
        ("E_MYAPP_VAR", "=-*Path", r"[~];C:\folder1", "TARGETDIR")
    ]
}
```

See the implementation of the `add_to_path` option in https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/blob/master/cx_Freeze/windist.py and the documentation of the [MSI Environment Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/environment-table).

But please BE CAREFUL: I've not tested this code and loosing the existing path information may prevent the computer from booting according to that documentation.